# Displaying "Hours" in mysql in Total hour column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(Min(Ontime), '%h:%i %p') AS Ontime, TIME_FORMAT(Max(Offtime), '%h:%i %p') AS Offtime, name,dates, TIME_FORMAT( SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(Offtime) - TIME_TO_SEC(Ontime))), "%H:%i") AS `totalHour` FROM netdoc where name='Michael' GROUP BY dates,name
```

> The results that are displaying

```
 Ontime  | Offtime |totalHours|
 10:06 AM  06:23 PM    08:16
```

> how can i do it like this?

```
Ontime    | Offtime  |totalHours|
 10:06 AM   06:23 PM   8 hours 16 minutes
```

Comment: just add the strings into final `TIME_FORMAT` like: `TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Offtime) - TIME_TO_SEC(Ontime))), "%H hours %i minutes")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **TIME_FORMAT** and below code will help you.

```
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Offtime) - TIME_TO_SEC(Ontime))), "%H hours %i minutes")
```